# how can i search custom post type and categories search in one custom query....?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, categories

I have three field 2 custom post type and 1 categories fields like:
[image]

and the result will be:
[image]

I have this 3 search fields(2 custom post type & 1 categories) dynamically and send another page via post method and I want to result using those 3 fields in a custom query/post type query, but I have no idea how can I write this type of query.

i am trying( see the attached code) but it is not working,

```
$post1 = $_POST['category'];//this is category 
$post2 = $_POST['type'];//this is custom post type field
$post3 = $_POST['where'];//this is custom post type field
$attachments = get_posts(array(
'post_type' => 'project',
'meta_value' => [$post1, $post2, $post3],
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_status' => 'any',
'post_parent' => null
));
if ($attachments) {
                                        foreach ($attachments as $post) {
                                            setup_postdata($post);

// all the fetch details 
}
                                        wp_reset_postdata();
                                    }
```